# Sending a SIP request using Java

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I need to create an app which sends SIP requests to an existing sip server. I need for now to only be able to send a registration request to the server.

I tried reading about it and found an example here:

http://alex.bikfalvi.com/teaching/upf/2013/architecture_and_signaling/lab/sip/

however, almost all examples over the internet use this JAIN Sip API. Isn't there also a sip package that comes with Java without installing additional things besides the Java SDK that will enable me to simply send a SIP request? When I try to import javax.sip, I get an error saying the import cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

No SIP is not including in the JDK.
I would recommend going higher level and use the SIP Servlets Specification and use an open source container https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets.
There is an example of what you want to achive here https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/tree/master/sip-servlets-examples/uac-register